# How to replace a signal for managing cached and network data with ReactiveCocoa

Tags: ios, objective-c, caching, reactive-programming, reactive-cocoa

I am trying to implement something similar to what discussed there https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/issues/1176 where a signal is returned by the cache manager and then a new signal is returned by the network when data has been refreshed.

This approach works fine when you're actually working with data that has been saved in cache and that has to be refreshed from the network.

Then I added pagination of data (the server is actually returning pages of data given an index and the number of items per page). 
What happens now is that I need to distinguish whether the signal I'm getting is from the cache or the network because I need to know if I should concatenate the results to my array of items shown in the UI or if I should replace some of them with those coming from the network signal.

At first I thought I could add a flag to the models that tells whether it's a cached response or a network one. But maybe there's something built into RactiveCocoa that fits my need in a better way.

Here's the code I came up with for the meanwhile.
This part is the one being called to load data. It first asks the cache and then fires the network signal. After each network call, the cache is also being refreshed (the cache is a SQLite database where I store the request path, request parameters and response body)

```
- (RACSignal *)getRanking:(NSString *)typeRanking userId:(NSString *)userId skip:(NSInteger)skip take:(NSInteger)take {
    NSParameterAssert(typeRanking != nil);
    NSParameterAssert(userId != nil);
    NSParameterAssert(skip >= 0);
    NSParameterAssert(take > 0);
    NSMutableDictionary *options = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    options[@"typeRanking"] = typeRanking;
    options[@"IdUser"] = userId;
    options[@"skip"] = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:skip];
    options[@"take"] = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:take];
    NSURLRequest *request = [self requestWithMethod:@"GET" path:@"/api/ranking/GetRanking" parameters:options];
    RACSignal *cachedSignal = [[ALTCacheManager sharedInstance] fetchCachedData:request];
    cachedSignal = [cachedSignal flattenMap:^RACStream *(id value) {
        NSLog(@"%@", value);
        return [self parsedResponseOfClass:ALTRankingResponse.class fromJSON:value];
    }];
    RACSignal *networkSignal =  [[self enqueueRequest:request resultClass:ALTRankingResponse.class cacheResponse:YES] alt_parsedResults];
    return [cachedSignal takeUntilReplacement:networkSignal];
}
```

My ViewModel is simply the following code:

```
@interface ALTChartViewModel ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) ALTRankingModel *rankingModel;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *rankingPositions;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger rowsForLastBatch;
@end

@implementation ALTChartViewModel

-(instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (!self) return nil;

    self.rankingPositions = [NSArray array];
    self.rowsForLastBatch = -1;

    return self;
}

- (RACSignal *) loadRanking:(NSString *)typeRanking skip:(NSInteger)skip take:(NSInteger)take {
    if (self.rowsForLastBatch == 0) return [RACSignal empty];
    RACSignal *signal = [RACSignal createSignal:^RACDisposable *(id<RACSubscriber> subscriber) {
        [[[ALTWSClient sharedInstance] getRanking:typeRanking userId:@"" skip:skip take:take] subscribeNext:^(ALTRankingResponse *response) {
            self.rankingModel = response.dataObject;
            self.rankingPositions = [self.rankingPositions arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:self.rankingModel.ranking];
            self.rowsForLastBatch = self.rankingModel.ranking.count;
            [subscriber sendNext:nil];
            [subscriber sendCompleted];
        }];
        return nil;
    }];
    return signal;
}



@end
```

What's happening now is that first the cached data is added to the `rankingPositions` array and then the network data is added to that same array. Instead I'd like to either add or replace that chunk of the array based on the kind of signal received.

Maybe I'm just overthinking all of this and I should just check each row returned and either add or replace it in my array based on the fact that I already have it in there or not (it's ordered data so that can be done just by looking at the position).

Comment: If your "ranking" objects could have some sort of unique identifier or hash code, you could easily decide whether you need to update an existing object or add a new object to the array based on a set membership test, without having to write special-case code for which signal the value was delivered from.

Comment: Unfortunately the server isn't issuing a unique isentifier. On the other hand, all my models inherit from a base class so I could just come up with a calculated hash per class.